# Why am I encountering the error 'Starting FGS without a type' when executing the code on Android 14?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code A works well in Android 13 or low, but I get the Error A when I run it in Android 14?

How can I fix it?

**Code A**

```
 private fun startForegroundService() {
        val builder = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {            
            val  mChannelName = getString(R.string.app_name)
            val notificationManager = this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                mChannelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW 
            )
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
            NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notificationChannel.id)
        } else {
            NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        }

        val myIntent = Intent(this, ActivityMain::class.java)        
     
        myIntent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0,
            myIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify_icon)            
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notificationTitle))
            .setTicker(getString(R.string.notificationTicker ))      //It will show text on status bar, even without having user to "pull down" the incoming notification.
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.notificationContent))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val notification = builder.build()       
        notification.flags = notification.flags or NotificationCompat.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT or NotificationCompat.FLAG_NO_CLEAR

        startForeground(125, notification)
    }
```

**Error A**

```
  android.app.MissingForegroundServiceTypeException: Starting FGS without a type  callerApp=ProcessRecord{8eb0601 12195:com.hicalc.soundrecorder/u0a190} targetSDK=34
                                                                                                        at android.app.MissingForegroundServiceTypeException$1.createFromParcel(MissingForegroundServiceTypeException.java:53)
                                                                                                        at android.app.MissingForegroundServiceTypeException$1.createFromParcel(MissingForegroundServiceTypeException.java:49)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableInternal(Parcel.java:4870)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From Android 14 (sdk 34) you have to set foreground service type.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required#permission-for-fgs-type

Check SDK version when attempting to go foreground:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        startForeground(SERVICE_ID, notification)
} else {
        startForeground(SERVICE_ID, notification, 
FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK)
}
```

and update the manifest:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_xxx"
    android:minSdkVersion="34" />


<application ...>
    <service
        android:name=".feature.exerciseplayer.data.service.YourService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:foregroundServiceType="xxx" />
```

Note: replace `xxx` by the service type that suits you.

Comment: TIRAMISU is 33, so the condition should be rather if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 34) {
or <= instead of <

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the permission to the manifest, and you also need to add foregroundServiceType to the service in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_SPECIAL_USE" />

<service
            android:name="service"
            android:label="Service"
            android:foregroundServiceType="specialUse" />
```

And then you need to check the SDK version to add the service type for Android 14:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34) {
    service.startForeground(
            NOTIFICATION_ID,
            notification,
            ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_SPECIAL_USE);
}else {
    service.startForeground(
            NOTIFICATION_ID,
            notification);
}
```